# How to remove EGIT from Eclipse Kepler?

Tags: java, egit, eclipse-kepler

I'm using the J2EE bundle of Eclipse Kepler, and I'm working with Git.

I'm also using [git-extension](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/) as a UI to git, and I wouldn't trade it for anything else, so for me egit is just an annoyance that brings information that I don't want on my screen.

How can I permanently remove it from eclispe ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's easiest to just disable EGIT from automatically managing your projects at import via Window - Preferences - Team - Git - Projects:

[image]

This will stop new projects from being managed, but projects that were imported before the change will still need EGIT to be disabled manually for the project. You can just right click -> Team -> Disconnect and they will no longer be managed by EGIT.

Comment: Projects that have already automatically connected to git will remain connected to git. But you can just right click -> Team -> Disconnect and disconnect them from git as well.

Comment: Good suggestion. I need to disable git for my legacy project on cvs. I put thus project on GIT which easier for me to do changes comparison.

Answer (score 32):

Just right click your project, and choose team > disconnect

Comment: should we have to do that for every project we pull?

Comment: Note that if you close and reopen a project it will be connected again.

Answer (score 17):

Found this link -> http://blog.sarathonline.com/2012/05/eclipse-indigo-without-mylyn.html

Please read the whole link, but in case it goes dead these are the move instructions from that link.

```
# cd path/to/eclipse/installation

mkdir disabled disabled/features disabled/plugins

# Disable egit/jgit
mv features/*egit* disabled/features/
mv plugins/*jgit* disabled/plugins/
mv plugins/*egit* disabled/plugins
```

Comment: @Andreas_D.  Thanks for pointing it out, added `hated` manual feature removal.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't find a better solution too (although I wouldn't want to disable EGit..). Didn't even find a global way to disconnect all projects by default.

Comment: @Andreas_D: Worked perfectly with Kepler (Build id: 20130614-0229).

Comment: Where is that folder with Mars?

Comment: On Mars.1(4.5.1), problem occurs. Bundled plugin ["Code Recommenders Snipmatch" depends on git plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/#snipmatch-preferences).