# Is there any way to deactivate Git support in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

In Eclipse Kepler Git support is provided by default. I don't like to have source control in my IDE, I prefer to use the shell for that.

I can't unistall that plugin. I can't disable git support for a project. I can't even hide Gif info in the Package Explorer view.

Is there any way to disable git support or at least hide git info?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408483/how-to-remove-egit-from-eclipse-kepler should do the trick...

Comment: Besides, in "Preferences > Team > Git > Label Decoration" I found how to disable overlay decoration in views