# How to prevent Eclipse from automatically committing changes after every save

Tags: eclipse, git, github-for-windows

I am trying to set up GitHub Desktop (3.3.1.0) on Windows 10 with an existing Eclipse Java project, created in Eclipse (Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)). I am able to initialize and successfully make an initial commit and push. However, after every file save operation in Eclipse, a new commit message appears in GitHub Desktop with the following description, `{"types":"C","runs":0}`.

Can anyone explain this behavior? I assume that it is the Eclipse editor that is automatically committing my changes because I tried saving changes in Atom and no such commit message appeared.

I also attempted to uninstall and disable EGit using the [instructions found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408483/how-to-remove-egit-from-eclipse-kepler), but this seemed to have no effect.

Comment: Does the issue persists with an Eclipse Neon 4.6? (https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/) Do you have any Git hooks in your repo which might explain this behavior?

Comment: @VonC Thanks - there weren't any Git hooks that would explain this, but I upgraded to Neon 4.6 and am no longer experiencing the issue.